# IF/IF Else with OR Statments Skipping

Tags: excel, vba

So i'm writing an and statement which also checks if a value is x or y for example. However it only executes the code if its the first x statement is true and not the y statement is true in my or statement.

So basically when my value in value in cell 17 = "Recovery Demand Issued" it skips the second else if statement, but, its fine when the value in cell 17 = "In Recovery"

Unsure why it skips the second else if statement, have I strucutured by and/or statement incorrectly?

```
If dataSheet.Cells(x, 6) = "Serena Hayward" And dataSheet.Cells(x, 8) = "Open" And dataSheet.Cells(x, 17) = "In Recovery" Or dataSheet.Cells(x, 17) = "Recovery Demand Issued" Then serenaBool = True


If chantalBool = True And cellDateDbl <= julyFinishDbl And cellDateDbl >= julyStartDbl Then
chantalJulyTotalDemanded = dataSheet.Cells(x, 10) + chantalJulyTotalDemanded

ElseIf serenaBool = True And cellDateDbl <= julyFinishDbl And cellDateDbl >= julyStartDbl Then
serenaJulyTotalDemanded = dataSheet.Cells(x, 10) + serenaJulyTotalDemanded
```

Answer (score 0):

i Would personally lay it out like below as yours is quite difficult to debug, notice the () around the 'or' arguments in the if statements.

```
        Sub test()
        Dim serenabool As Boolean
            serenabool = False
        Dim chantelbool As Boolean
            chantelbool = False

        If datasheet.Cells(x, 6) = "Serena Hayward" And datasheet.Cells(x, 8) = "Open" And (datasheet.Cells(x, 17) = "In Recovery" Or datasheet.Cells(x, 17) = "Recovery Demand Issued") Then serenabool = True
        If datasheet.Cells(x, 6) = "Chantel Surname" And datasheet.Cells(x, 8) = "Open" And (datasheet.Cells(x, 17) = "In Recovery" Or datasheet.Cells(x, 17) = "Recovery Demand Issued") Then chantelbool = True

        If chantalBool = True And cellDateDbl <= julyFinishDbl And cellDateDbl >= julyStartDbl Then
        chantalJulyTotalDemanded = datasheet.Cells(x, 10) + chantalJulyTotalDemanded
        End If

        If serenabool = True And cellDateDbl <= julyFinishDbl And cellDateDbl >= julyStartDbl Then
        serenaJulyTotalDemanded = datasheet.Cells(x, 10) + serenaJulyTotalDemanded
        End If

        Debug.Print "Serena is " & serenabool
        Debug.Print "Chantel is " & chantelbool

        End Sub
```